# Auto scroll in ScrollView react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am creating chat app and want to auto scroll to bottom automatically in `ScrollView` every time a new message received.

Here is my code:

```
<ScrollView>
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.dataSource}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <SenderChatRow data={item} />}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
  />
  {this._bookingRequestMessage()}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thank you but now when i open keyboard the scrollview won't scroll to bottom\

Answer (score 13):

From React Native 0.41 and later you can use this:

```
<ScrollView
    ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}
    onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight)=>{        
        this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({animated: true});
    }}>
</ScrollView>
```

> Take a look at [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrolltoend)

### Update

As you mentioned you have problem when the keyboard is open, first:

`import { Keyboard } from "react-native";`

Then use `componentDidMount()`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', 
    this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this));
}


componentWillUnmount() {
  this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
  this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
}

_keyboardDidShow() {
  this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: false })
}
```

> Thanks [chetan godiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9224401/chetan-godiya) for the update!

Comment: worked after removing  **this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();**  from **componentWillUnmount()**

Answer (score 0):

for scrollview
add this lines into your scrollview

```html
<ScrollView
            ref={(ref) => this.flatListRef = ref}
            contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
            onContentSizeChange={(width, height) => this.flatListRef.scrollToEnd({ animated: false })}
          >
```

and then import Keyboard from react-native add then add this code into your script

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this));
}
}

 componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }
  
  _keyboardDidShow() {
    this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: false })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to doing the same like **scrolling** the screen in click of a button.

```
const [offset,setOffset] = useState(0);
        const scrollViewRef = useRef();
    
    const scrollDown = () => {
        const y = offset + 101;  /// we can get the height from the onLayout in view
        scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({x: 0, y, animated: true});
        setOffset(y);
    }
    
    return (
        <ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef} >
            <Button onPress={scrollDown} title="Scroll down" />
            <Text>
                  [ Very long text here where user has to scroll ]
            </Text>
        </ScrollView>
    )
```